# IDE Error removing reference in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I remove a reference to a project in Visual Studio 2008 I receive the following error message in a dialog box:

> Attempting to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Once I click "OK" to exit the message box, Visual Studio shuts down completely.  I'm running Visual Studio on a Windows 7(x64) machine.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack but you might try removing the reference by editing the project file or solution file with a text editor and then open the project again. **Be sure to backup first**.

Look for  `<ProjectReference Include="` or  `<Reference Include="` in the project file and remove the one you need to get ride of.

Look for `Project ... EndProject` in the solution file

Comment: I could do that...but it doesn't solve my problem as to why the editor is crashing when I do such as simple function.

Comment: It looks like people have this problem when referencing Office Introps and or reference the wrong version of a third party library (meaning VS2008 thinks the libraries version is 4.1 but actually the dll is version 4.2). I would make a copy of your solution then manually remove references and then re-add them from within VS. There is a good chance that after doing this your problem will be fixed and you will be able to add/remove reference normally again.